# Can I edit an app made by Google AppInventor with other programming environment?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, app-inventor

So I see that making an Android App with Google AppInventor is really easy comparing to make it manually using Android plugin for Eclipse. But since AppInventor abilities are limited, is there any way I could change any element of an app made by it with Eclipse or any other programming environment that allow me to change the code manually?

Answer (score 7):

As you may know, you cannot do so directly, since App Inventor code is converted into Scheme, then converted by the kawa compiler into Java byte code.  It is never represented in Java.

However, the team has released the component libraries open source, which can help people make the transition from App Inventor to the Java SDK.  See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/app-inventor-instructors/browse_thread/thread/10a64e64b7886afb?pli=1) and [this tutorial](http://groups.google.com/group/app-inventor-instructors/browse_thread/thread/57d3e50d5dc8d73).  A team at the University of Alabama is building a tool to automatically translate App Inventor code to Java.  See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/app-inventor-instructors/browse_thread/thread/cf39ec1234f4afa8/f54975fea4d4f813?lnk=gst&q=joshua%20swank#f54975fea4d4f813) and [this project site](http://code.google.com/p/appinventor-java-translation/).

Answer (score 0):

You could download the .aia file and change the file extension to a .zip. Then you can access the files, and maybe even open it in android studio.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be helping to raise your content quality