# App Inventor source code

Tags: app-inventor

After Google discontinued its support of Android App Inventor on December 31st 2011, it has been taken up by Massachusetts Institute of Technology - Center for Mobile Learning, and will be re-launching its service in Q1 2012 for general public access.

Currently it is impossible to extract the source code from your former projects, does MIT plan to support this? Has there been any progress in doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by extracting the source code?  Do you mean downloading your projects from the Google server or something else?

Comment: No, I have already downloaded my projects. I mean that App Inventor is GUI based programming although it is impossible to view the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you download your project and unzip it, you *can* see the source code: the list of components used, their properties, the blocks used, how they are connected, etc.  That's probably not what you want, though.

If you're asking about seeing Java source code, that's not possible.  App Inventor programs are never represented as Java code.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558243/can-i-edit-an-app-made-by-google-appinventor-with-other-programming-environment) .

Comment: Looks like I'll just need to be patient and root for the University of Alabama! Seems like this isn't impossible.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean.  I'd say that you can't "extract" Java source code from App Inventor projects, because it's not part of them.  You're right that someone is working on writing an App Inventor to Java translator.  Source code in any language can (in principle) be translated into any language that is as or more powerful.